# Can you create an ssis loop for each row of a dynamics source from a xml fetch?

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I am trying to create a csv file for every work order that gets created, I want to run an ssis package and using kingswaysoft, I need a way to run the loop for every row from the source.

Also if there is an alternative to this I am open to ideas.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kingswaysoft, but generally: this depends on the structrue of your XML. If it is a "simple" xml, you could use a C# script component or the basic XML source in order to load the content into an object variable and in the next step loop over this object variable. If it is a complex XML and you need XSLT style sheets etc., I would suggest the C# component source and proceed as described above. This ways you can store each value per row into a variable and create a csv file from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this easily using the SSIS **For Loop** Container.